Same material on different objects, different reflection
I have different objects with the same material applied. The direction of the light reflecting from the surface, seems to differ. I tried applying rotation and scale but it didn't change anything, except messing up the models that have an Array Modifier on them. Any ideas how I can fix this?


Hello and welcome to BSE. Are you referring to the seam? Or do you mean the vertical bar is darker than the diagonal bar? Can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Hello. In the scene there are three objects. The upper and the lower ones have an array modifier on them, the middle one has none. The texture transition within the array object is smooth, but between the middle section and the other two sections there is a line. And the "shininess" also is different. https://blend-exchange.com/b/R3WbRAbp

Your Color Space of the Image Texture nodes should be non-color except for the Base Color Image Texture. They are currently set to sRGB.

I see.. Thank you Harry, that fixed it!

The Color Space option of the Image Texture nodes should be Non-Color except for the Base Color Image Texture which should be sRGB.

In addition to Harry McKenzie's answer
In your material, the normal is image-based,  in Tangent space. That means  the local 3D spin of X and Y directions about the Z normal is dependent on the U and V directions in the UV map.
The UV map of the middle section of your mesh is at right-angles to the UV map of the arrayed section, with respect to their surfaces:

.. and needs to be rotated -90°, for consistency.

If you can commit the time, the UV mapping could be simplified, altogether.
